# JSF form dynamic layout causes java.lang.IllegalStateException: component with duplicate id "j_id142" found

Tags: jsf, foreach, duplicates, jstl, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to build a dynamic layout for a form in JSF. It should generate a dynamic number of select fields, based on the values that come from "classifyingOptions", which is of type: Map(Object, List(Object)).

I first tried to use ui:repeat to iterate through the map, but I couldn't since the EL for the u:select and f:selectItems are evaluated when the view is built and is invalid since it relies on a variable only made available by the ui:repeat during rendering.(source for the explanation [here](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat)

So i switched to using c:forEach.

```
    <c:forEach items="#{action.classifyingOptions}" var="current" varStatus="i">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <u:select label="#{current.key.value}" id="select_#{i.index}" value="#{action.selectedOption}"
    readonly="#{i.index != 0 ? !action.isSelected.get(i.index -1) : false }"
    valueChangeListener="#{action.classifyingOptionChanged}" immediate="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{current.value}" var="option" itemValue="#{option.key}" itemLabel="#{option.value}" />
    <a4j:ajax event="change" render="@form" execute="@this" />
    </u:select>
    <h:panelGroup />
    </h:panelGrid>
    </c:forEach>
```

I can read the map and show the select fields. The requirements is that when the first of the fields is selected, the next field needs to be enabled using an ajax call.
The problem is that an error is thrown on the sever once I select an option for the first field: 
        16.05.16 16:46:25:267 EEST] 0000006f FaceletViewDe E   Error Rendering View[/pages/details.xhtml]                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: component with duplicate id "j_id142" found

In the browser, i get this message as part of the response that threw the error: This page contains the following errors: error on line 23 at column 230: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

So I used both ui:repeat and c:forEach, but none of them was able to work properly. Can you check where my mistake is? Or do you know any different approach?
Thank you!

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Tried the latest?

Comment: The project is using JSF 2.0 and RichFaces 4.3.5.Final

Comment: The version of MyFaces is 2.1.9

Comment: That's almost 4 years old. Can you reproduce the problem on current MyFaces 2.2.10?

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work with the latest version either.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved. I used f:ajax instead of a4j:ajax